# Using the same debug keystore on multiple computers

Tags: android, keystore

I'm developing on multiple computers.  If I deploy to my phone directly from Eclipse on one computer, I can't deploy from the other without uninstalling first.  I'm assuming this is because there is a debug certificate being used to sign the app, and they're not the same across the two machines.

Is it possible to copy one over to the other so that Eclipse is using the same one on both machines?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes.

In Unix like os the debug key is located by default in `~/.android/debug.keystore`

You also can choose a custom one from eclipse like in the following screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using Eclipse (i.e. using ant)?

Comment: @lowellk Just replace the debug.keystore in the .android location. Ant will use the replaced one.

Comment: @toro I want to be able to use different one for different projects as well. So I really need my keystore to live within my project folder, not in my home folder

Comment: You will need to clean the project on the 2nd computer once you change this setting, so it re-builds the debug apk using the new keystore.

Comment: This settings screen doesn't seem to exist anymore (Android Studio 3.4) . The file is in `C:\Users\User\.android` though.