# signing an application multiple developers

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working with a team using Eclipse to develop for android.  We often run into an issue that when a different developer has compiled the apk it won't install on the device with out uninstalling the app that was compiled by a different developer/machine.  I am assuming this is because of the automated signature process that eclipse runs when compiling..  but cant figure out how to change the settings/create a signature that we can all use.  our project is shared via SVN..

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924901/using-the-same-debug-keystore-on-multiple-computers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For production, use only one keystore that only the leader has, or give a copy to everyone (not recommended).

For development, pick your favorite machine, and take it's debug.keystore from ~/.android/debug.keystore. Then either paste it into the same location on the other machines, overwriting the existing one, or configure eclipse to use it as the debug keystore in the settings (Check in Android -> Build).

Comment: where do i find the debug.keystore?  in the android sdk?

Comment: Which operating system are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is best way, but if you all share a privateKey then just make sure to export your apk in Eclipse http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#ExportWizard

Probably a better way would to all share a debug key and only when the apk is ready for release have your lead sign it with the privateKey register with Google.

Comment: yeah for development purposes i guess we want to share the debug key.. but i can't find it.. we created a signature but for cant seem to assign the debug run to use it..

Comment: @Raghav's posts shows you where it is. You may not be able to see the ".android" folder because it's hidden. Make sure your viewing hidden files.