# Generate an OAuth 2.0 client ID on google play service

Tags: android, oauth, google-play-services, keystone

I am trying to set up linking app for OAuth 2.0 client ID from following official instruction:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#step_3_generate_an_oauth_20_client_id

I found a problem: the "Certificate fingerprint: SHA1" is created from one computer's debug.keystone. So running app on android device from that computer is perfect.

But if I changed to another computer to develop, even the code are the same, the running app will error out(because the fingerprint not match). If I need to use multiple computer for development the sample app(for example, synchroniced by git), how do I manage to run the app smoothly from all computer? Is that possible? Do I just copy over the same keystone?

Thanks

---update:
I tried to copy over the debug.keystone, it doesn't work. The error message changed, but still show the fingerprint not match.

Comment: take a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924901/using-the-same-debug-keystore-on-multiple-computers  works like a boss